# Build a subtheme using acquia marina in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-themes

I used the  Acquia Marina theme to built a new sub theme. i had downloaded the fusion theme and Skinr module. now how can i proceed for the next step ? Is there any good tutorial site to help in this issues. I am using now drupal 7.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/build-a-sub-theme-under-acquia-marina-in-drupal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page may help you. http://fusiondrupalthemes.com/support/documentation Last weel I have changed theme to acquia marina http://vision4life.in. If you are using Drupal 7 then u need fusion accelerator and not skinr.